# c++ std transform calls copy constructor multiple times

Tags: algorithm, c++11

During implementation of a code copying of map elements into a vector I found out that `std::transform` calls the copy ctor of my custom class multiple times despite of prior vector size reservation. So I compared different ways to do this, and saw that the best method is a simple `for`-loop. So my question is: are these algorithms really more expensive? If so what is the advantage of them? Or does it not matter for small number of elements? Here my test code:

```
class A
{
public:
    A() {}
    A(int ai) : i(ai) {}
    A(A& a) : i(a.i) { std::cout << "copy ctor " << i << std::endl; }
    A(const A& a) : i(a.i) { std::cout << "copy const ctor " << i << std::endl; }
    A(A&& a) : i(std::move(a.i)) { std::cout << "move ctor " << i << std::endl; }    
    
    // I removed overloaded operators because they are not called here...

private:
    int i;
};

std::map<int, A> m;
m.insert(std::make_pair(0, A(7)));
m.insert(std::make_pair(1, A(3)));
m.insert(std::make_pair(2, A(1)));
 
std::vector<A> vec;

vec.reserve(m.size());
std::transform(m.begin(), m.end(), std::back_inserter(vec), [](const std::pair<int, A> & p) { return p.second; }); // 3 calls for each ctor

//... clean up and reserve vec
std::for_each(m.begin(), m.end(), [&vec](const std::pair<int, A> & p) { vec.push_back(p.second); }); // 2 calls for each ctor

//... clean up and reserve vec
for (const auto & p : m) // 1 call for each ctor
{
    vec.emplace_back(p.second);
}
```

Comment: One copy is cause by the type in the lambda. Replace `std::pair<int, A>` with auto and you should see one copy call dropped. Tested on godbolt.org.

Comment: Great! But as I compile with VS2012 I just removed `const &` instead of auto. You can provide it as an answer if you want...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element type in a `std::map` is `std::pair<const Key, Value>`.

In your example use use `std::pair<int, A>` without const, so you need to copy the pair. This adds a copy in the first two solutions. If you change it to `std::pair<const int, A>` you can see 2 constructor calls in the first iteration and only one in the second (on par with your for loop).

For the first iteration you now have 1 copy and one move. This is because your lambda needs to copy the A then back_inserter move constructs it into the vector. Normally I wouldn't worry about an extra move since they are supposed to be cheap.

However, you can get rid of it. We can force the lamba to not copy the A instance, by ,for example, specifying the return type to be a reference. So now the back_inserter will have to copy when it inserts, but that's it.

This version of your code does one copy per element for each solution:

```
std::map<int, A> m; m.insert(std::make_pair(0, A(7))); m.insert(std::make_pair(1, A(3))); m.insert(std::make_pair(2, A(1)));  std::vector<A> vec;

std::cout << "Transform" << std::endl;

vec.reserve(m.size());
std::transform(m.begin(), m.end(), std::back_inserter(vec),
     // changed the key type and return type.
     [](const std::pair<const int, A> & p)->const A& { return p.second; }); 

std::cout << "for_each" << std::endl;
vec.resize(0);
vec.reserve(m.size());
std::for_each(m.begin(), m.end(),
    // changed the key type.
    [&vec](const std::pair<const int, A> & p) { vec.push_back(p.second); });

std::cout << "START\n";
vec.resize(0);
vec.reserve(m.size());

for (const auto & p : m) {
    vec.emplace_back(p.second);
}
```